# Xcode 7 error when pushing changes

Tags: xcode, xcode7, git-push

I have faced a problem when I try to push changes of my project when I used Xcode 7, 7.0.1, 7.1,and lately 7.3 see the screenshot:

[image]

That never happened on Xcode 6.xx, just when I updated to Xcode 7 it occurred, Please provide me with any suggestion or answer as soon as possible.

Comment: @rmaddy what did you edit ?

Comment: Click on the "edited <timestamp>" link and see.

Answer (score 1):

Enter the required ccredentials or select another authentication method. "Authentication" is a drop-down menu where you can select "User name and Password" or "SSH Keys".

I use SSH Keys, select that option and click "OK".

Some form of authentication has always been required to push to a repository.

Comment: I entered the required credentials correctly but still showing me the same alert.

And I can't select SSH keys method, drop down menu is disabled as shown in the screenshot.

Comment: 1. Does it work hen you enter the correct credentials? 2. In order to use SSH keys you need to generate a certificate and upload the public key to the remote repository. The repository will have full instructions to do this.

Comment: 1.  No it does not work.
2. I don't know how to do that.

I can push changes when using Xcode 6.4 without problems.